# Sending data from client to server in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, httpwebrequest

I am developing a web application using spring MVC, Hiberbate and MySQL database. I am trying to send data to server from a client, but I can not do it.

In detail,
I want to send my JSON data to **http://localhost:8080/app/test** . In my *test controller* I want to get the data which comes from the client and write it to screen or save it to db. I have been searching about 3 days and I have tried many strategies to do it, but I can not.

Answer (score 1):

You must explicitly tell spring to use a json parser.
For instance, here is a piece of my DispatcherServlet config :

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jsonConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
</bean>
```

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) Must be in your classpath.

Then you write a method like this one in your annotated controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void myMethod(@RequestBody MyObject object) {
    //... do what you want with the object
}
```

You just have to send an JSON object with properties that match the ones in MyObject, via a POST request.

Comment: POST and GET methods caused problem :(. Get works fine, but when I use post the web page can not found.

Comment: You just have a 404 ? Nothing more in the logs ? Maybe you should try to add the "@ResponseBody" annotation to the method. I do not remember if it is mandatory with void methods, so give it a try.

Comment: Sometimes 404 but so many times 405 :( I tried adding @ResponseBody annotation but I did not work.

Comment: How do you submit the data on the client side ?

Comment: I have submit the data from my other computer to server.

Comment: Yes, but how ? Do you post it with the right headers (Content-type : application/json) ?  Do you post it using jquery, or other javascript library ?

Comment: I solved the problem. I used some objectmapper library instead of json. Thx for your suggestions .